# How To insert Bulk from datatable to excel

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using npoi to save data in excel sheet,but i have a huge data it takes more than 1 hour when trying to insert data like that so i'm trying to insert data bulk into excel sheet.

```
public byte[] getWorkbook(DataTable dt)
{
    IRow currentRow;
    HSSFWorkbook workbook;
    var worksheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

    for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        currentRow=worksheet.CreateRow(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            currentRow.CreateCell(j).SetCellValue(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
            worksheet.AutoSizeColumn(j);
        }
    }

     var stream =new MemoryStream();
     workbook.Write(stream);
     return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading each value from DataTable and moving it cell by cell in excel is a usual way of transferring data. But for bulk data, this procedure is not recommended because of time complexity.
So to overcome this we can use clipboard to copy data from DataTable and we can paste it into the range of excel.It improves performance.

To achieve this, DataTable don't have default function to copy data to clipboard. So we have to convert Datatable to array and from array to sting. And string can be easily copied to clipboard and can be pasted in Excel.

Please find a link for reference [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/842169/Bulk-data-Export-to-Excel-from-Datatable-and-Datag)